# Select number from a string classic asp

Tags: asp-classic

I need to get a 4/5 digit number which always comes directly after a #

For example it'll be "Item Title (#1234)" however it's not always in the same place or at the end.

Not sure how I go about doing that

Comment: You should really try describing the problem in more detail and at least show some kind of code attempt then we may be able to help you. For more information see [ask]. As it stands this question *(at the moment)* is [off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and *likely* will be [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: There is a couple of things you can try, look at `InStr()` *(locates a string pattern and reports the position of the first character in the pattern or returns 0 if not found)*. Using `InStr()` in conjuntion with `Mid()` should allow you to pull out the number *(especially if it is always surrounded with `(` `)`)*. Depending on how complex the string is you might find using the [tag:vbscript] `RegEx` object a better approach.

Comment: Another way *(but not recommended)* is to step through each character in the string and build up the number by identifying if the correct is numeric or not, can do this with a simple `For ... Next` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to manually parse the string.

I've made a quick function for this:

```vbs
'//return the number after delimeter string, if exists (first occurance only)
'//in case no number exists, returns Empty value
Function FindNumberAfter(rawValue, delimeterString)
    Dim index, x, curChar
    Dim sBuffer
    FindNumberAfter = vbEmpty
    index = InStr(rawValue, delimeterString)
    If index>0 Then
        For x=index+Len(delimeterString) To Len(rawValue)
            curChar = Mid(rawValue, x, 1)
            If IsNumeric(curChar) Then
                sBuffer = sBuffer & curChar
            Else  
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If Len(sBuffer)>0 Then FindNumberAfter = CLng(sBuffer)
    End If
End Function
```

Usage in your case:

```
Response.Write(FindNumberAfter("Item Title (#1234)", "#"))
```